# WCF proxy faulted but does not throw an exception

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a method which accesses a service to perform two calls. Here is the (simplified) client code:

```
try
{
    using (var client = new IntegrationServiceClient())
    {
        int taskID = client.CreateTask(param, taskType, taskDate);
        if (taskID < 0)
        {
            //There was some error
            return -1;
        }

        if (!client.ExecuteTask(taskID, taskType))
        {
            //There was some error
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    LogManager.Log("Error while creating and executing task", ex);
}
```

I'm getting a `CommunicationObjectFaultedException` exception only on the second call. How is this possible? If there was some kind of fault, shouldn't I get a `FaultException` (or some other exception) after the first call? Is there something other than an exception that can cause the proxy to enter a faulted state?

Comment: It probably gets faulted on the second call. Is there an `InnerException`?

Comment: Another question, does it work when you are using a new `IntegrationServiceClient` for the second call?

Comment: The log file doesn't show any inner exceptions, but I don't believe the `LogManager` will display them. I refactored the code to put each call in its own using and its own try-catch. I'm now getting a `CommunicationObjectFaultedException` on the first call.

Comment: Ahh I see, it's raising that exception when attempting to dispose / close the proxy. But I still need to find out what's causing the proxy to become faulted in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there was a bad `web.config` file. The stack trace was telling me there was an error on line with the second call because that was the last meaningful line within the `using` statement, after which the proxy is disposed. The `CommunicationObjectFaultedException` is raised only when disposing the proxy.

It was just the way that the code was written that caused the stack trace look like the exception was thrown when calling the second method.